# Python Dash: concurrently updating an element within a callback

Tags: python, socket.io, callback, plotly-dash

In dash, I would like to update one element with intermediate information from the process that generates the main output (live update). I have a basic example below in which I wish to update the children of the *update-output*-id after each `print()` statement with the value of s.

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
import pandas as pd

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Button("execute callback", id="button"),
        html.Div(children="live updated of progress", id="update-output"),
        html.Div(children="wait for final output", id="final-output"),
    ]
)

@app.callback(
    Output("update-output", "children"),
    Output("final-output", "children"),
    Input("button", "n_clicks")
)
def change_text(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks is None:
        raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3],[2, 3, 4]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
        s = 'df1 done'
        print(s) # return s, dash.no_update
        
        df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3],[2, 3, 4]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
        s = 'df2 done'
        print(s) # return s, dash.no_update
        
        df3 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3],[2, 3, 4]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
        s = 'df3 done'
        print(s) # return s, dash.no_update
        
        df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
        
        return s, str(df.to_dict('records'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: You can use a [`dcc.Interval`](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/interval) component to fire the callback periodically. By default you would set it to disabled=true, enable it when the button is clicked, and disable it once the final data are returned. In this case you will need to use specific functions and/or global variables to set, reset, and keep track of the elapsed time and the actual value of s.

Comment: Thanks EricLavault, I think my example was a stupid one and I changed it to one that is a bit more applicable to what I would like to do.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone will come across this question. I adapted my solution from [here](https://dash.plotly.com/long-callbacks) (example 3).

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.long_callback import DiskcacheLongCallbackManager
import pandas as pd
import time
import diskcache


cache = diskcache.Cache("./cache")
long_callback_manager = DiskcacheLongCallbackManager(cache)

app = dash.Dash(__name__, long_callback_manager=long_callback_manager)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Button("Submit", id="button"),
        html.Button("Cancel", id="cancel_button", disabled=True),
        html.Div(children="live updated", id="update-output"),
        html.Div(children="wait for final output", id="final-output"),
    ]
)

@app.long_callback(
    Output("final-output", "children"),
    Input("button", "n_clicks"),
    running=[
        (Output("button", "disabled"), True, False),
        (Output("cancel_button", "disabled"), False, True),
    ],
    cancel=[Input("cancel_button", "n_clicks")],
    progress=[Output("update-output", "children")], 
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def change_text(set_progress, n_clicks):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3],[2, 3, 4]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
    s = 'df1 done'
    set_progress([s])
    time.sleep(1)
    
    df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3],[2, 3, 4]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
    s = 'df2 done'
    set_progress([s])
    time.sleep(1)
    
    df3 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3],[2, 3, 4]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
    s = 'df3 done'
    set_progress([s])
    time.sleep(1)
    
    df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
    
    return str(df.to_dict('records'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```